# Send an entire web app as 1 HTTP response (html, js, css, images, ...)

Tags: performance, http, browser, web-applications

Traditionally a browser will parse HTML and then send further requests to the server for all related data. This seems like inefficient to me, since it might require a large number of requests, even though my server already knows that a browser that wants to use this web application will need all of it's resources.

I know that js and css could be inlined, but that complicates server side code and img data as base64 bloats the size of the data... I'm aware as well that rendering can start before all assets are downloaded, which would potentially no longer work (depending on the implementation). I still feel that streaming an entire application in one go should be faster on slow connections than making tens of requests separately.

Ideally I would like the server to stream an entire directory into one HTTP response.

Does any model for this exist?
Does the reasoning make sense?

ps: If browser support for this is completely lacking, I'm wondering about a 2 step approach. Download a small JavaScript which downloads a compressed web app file, extracts it and plugs the resources into the page. Is anyone already doing something like this?

**Update**
I found one: http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/read-load-files-from-zip-in-javascript/

Comment: You would need to change the HTTP protocol and redesign browsers to work with this new model.

Comment: Don't forget that browsers cache many of the components, so they don't have to be downloaded every time.

Comment: @Barmar I know, but they could cache the entire version of the web app too. If data is fetched through ajax, then the app only changes once per release of a new version.

Comment: It's more efficient to keep them separate. The HTML can change but the JS stays the same, so they'll use the cached JS while re-downloading the HTML. And many images never change.

Comment: Anyway, it's unclear what you're asking about. There's no current method to do what you want, you're talking about a big redesign of web protocols.

Answer (score 0):

I started to research related issues in order to find the way to get best results with what seems possible without changing web standards, and I wondered about caching. If I could send the last modified date of every subresource of a page along with the initial HTML page, a browser could avoid asking if modified headers once it has loaded every resource at least once. This would in effect be better than to send all resources with the initial request, since that would be beneficial only on the first load, and detrimental on subsequent loads, since it would be better for browsers to use their cache (as Barmar pointed out).

Now it turns out that even with a web extension you can not get hold of the if-modified-since header and so you surely can't tell the browser to use the cached version instead of contacting the server.

I then found this post from [Facebook](https://code.facebook.com/posts/557147474482256/this-browser-tweak-saved-60-of-requests-to-facebook/) on how they tried to reduce traffic by hashing their static files and giving them a 1 year expiry date. This would mean that the url garantuees the content of the file. They still saw plenty of unnecessary if-modified-since requests and they managed to convince Firefox and Chrome to change the behaviour of their reload buttons to no longer reload static resources. For Firefox this requires a new `cache-control: immutable` header, for Chrome it doesn't.

I then remembered that I had seen something like that before and it turns out there is a solution for this problem which is more convenient than hashing the contents of resources and serving them from a database for at least ten years. It is to just a new version number in the filename. The even more convenient solution would be to just add a version query string, but it [turns out that that doesn't always work](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/).

Admittedly, changing your filenames all the time is a nuisance, because files referencing these files also need to change. However the files don't actually need to change. If you control the server it might be as simple as writing a redirect rule to make sure that `logo.vXXXX.png` will be redirected to `logo.png` (where XXXX is the last modified timestamp in seconds since epoch)[1]. Now let your template system automatically generate the timestamp, like in wordpress' `wp_enqueue_script`. WordPress actually satisfies itself with the query string technique. Now you can set the expiration date to a far future and use the immutable cache header. If browsers respect the cache control, you can now safely ignore etags and if-modified-since headers, since they are now completely redundant.

This solution guarantees the browser shall never ask for cache validation and yet you shall never see a stale resource, without having to decide on the expiry date in advance.

It doesn't answer the original question here about how to avoid having to do multiple requests to fetch the resources on the same page on a clean cache, but ever after (as long as the browser cache doesn't get cleared), you're good! I suppose that's good enough for me.

[1] You can even avoid the server overhead of checking the timestamp on every resource every time a page references it by using the version number of your application. In debug mode, for development, one can use the timestamp to avoid having to bump the version on every modification of the file.